# Are there official sources that include stat blocks for NPC Monks?

Tags: dnd-5e, npc, class

NPCs emulating character classes are many. A very incomplete list would include: Abjurer, Archer, Blackguard, Bard, Champion, Conjurer, Diviner, Druid...

You get the idea.

Among the monsters there's the *Hobgoblin Iron Shadow* and the *Shadar-kai Shadow Dancer*, but I'm struggling to find Monks among the NPCs in the sources I own so far. I'm hoping to represent various Monk subclasses in NPCs, and I'm looking for the balance that I attribute to the officially-made NPCs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This search](https://www.dndbeyond.com/search?q=Monk&f=monsters&c=monsters) at D&D Beyond has several, including stat blocks from the *Monster Manual*, *Candlekeep*, *Princes of the Apocalypse*, *Call of the Netherdeep*, and *Lost Laboratory of Kwalish*.

[Searching instead for “unarmored defense”](https://www.dndbeyond.com/search?q=Unarmored%20Defense&f=monsters&c=monsters) yields many more results, including stat blocks from *Planescape*, *Volo’s Guide*, *Dragonheist*, *Eberron*, and *Storm King’s Thunder*.

Worth highlighting here is the adventure “The Book of Inner Alchemy” from *Candlekeep Mysteries* which contains several stat blocks for different levels of NPC monks.

Comment: I swear I searched "Monk". I have no idea what I did wrong. :) That second link is super helpful, too. I hadn't thought of searching by ability.